# Issue with video stream when header contains accept-ranges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, video-streaming

I am trying to stream video from server with `accept-ranges` to allow users to change position on client-side video player (in my case jwplayer)

When `accept-ranges` code is included client (jwplayer or opened only in chrome directly from url) plays about `15s` normally and after it is every chunk asked with new request, practically after 15s only goes through method only one time, connection is broken in or after `Response.Flush()` without any error (sometimes `Flush()` gets error code `0x800704CD` or `0x800703E3` or `0x80070016` in about 10% of requests), after that is `Response.IsClientConnected=false` so method ends.

Client is asked for range for example `123456-empty`, there is not specified end part of range.

I guess that this is not right behavior, maybe there is wrong headers on Response.. or is normal, that client video player is creating new request for every chunk? Actually it takes on my PC about 80% of CPU.

Problem is only while streaming video and when is created a lot of new requests in same time, in usual situations when file is downloaded there is no problem when is establishment of broken downloads for example.

When accept-ranges code missing, there is no problem in video streaming, all server->clients transfers are in while loop and only when user broke connection methods end.

(`This solution is running under ASP.NET MVC4`)

Currently used code :

```
    public void Method()
    {
        string path = @"filePath.mp4";
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
        long fileLength = file.Length;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
        long dataToRead = fileLength;
        long startbyte = 0;
        long location = 0;
        long readLength = 0;

        Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["Range"]))
        {
            string[] range = Request.Headers["Range"].Split(new char[] { '=', '-' });
            location = long.Parse(range[1]);
            if (location >= 0 && location <= fileLength)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 206;
                Response.AddHeader("content-range", String.Format(" bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", location, fileLength - 1, fileLength));
                startbyte = location;
                dataToRead = fileLength - startbyte;
                Response.AppendHeader("content-length", dataToRead.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", String.Format(" bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", 0, fileLength - 1, fileLength));
            Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileLength.ToString());
        }

        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                if (startbyte > 0)
                {
                    stream.Seek(startbyte, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }

                while (dataToRead > 0)
                {
                    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        readLength = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, (int)readLength);
                        Response.Flush();

                        dataToRead = dataToRead - readLength;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataToRead = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (EndOfStreamException endStream)
        {
            Log.Error(endStream.Message, endStream);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException timeout)
        {
            Log.Error(timeout.Message, timeout);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e.Message, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a side note: I have a similar solution with WCF and I never return more than 4MB for requests like `123456-empty`. it works with JWPlayer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, For some reason jwplayer can't specify end of range, do you have any special settings on client player initialization?(I have only file:url, image:url, width and height) Or do you have any differences in header settings to response? I think that there doesn't matter if it is wcf or asp.net or not? 4MB per request sounds great.

Comment: I think you should use `dataToRead` in `content-range` header. BTW: I also respond to `If-Modified-Since` header.

Comment: I repaired Content-range, there really should be length from started position (to end position or end of file), I tried to create similar application in wcf, but behavior is still same, finally I found, that this problem is more specific, it's only in Chrome (firefox and opera works fine) and only with one 3,3GB file (tested smaller but larger too - 8GB file without any problem)